# Elasticsearch query for "OR but not ALL"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

My ES document looks like this:

[image: Data Sample]

where ResponseQ1, ResponseQ2 and ResponseCompleted are integers and the rest are string text.

I need to create a query with the condition where either 1 or 2 (BUT not all 3) sub-conditions are fulfilled:

1. ResponseQ1:0
2. ResponseQ2:0
3. ResponseQ3:"skipped"

Doing a bool query with "should" can easily get me a simple OR relationship where 1, 2 or 3 of the subconditions are met, but I simply cannot figure out how to fulfill the "BUT not all 3 subconditions".

Would really appreciate some pointers on this, thanks.

I'm using ElasticSearch 2.2 running my queries through Kibana 4.4.1.

Comment: try using querystring query feature https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the `querystring query` below.

`(ResponseQ1:0 OR ResponseQ2:0 OR ResponseQ3:"skipped) NOT (ResponseQ1:0 AND Response Q2:0 AND ResponseQ3:"skipped")`

Comment: (ResponseQ1:0 OR ResponseQ2:0 OR ResponseQ3:"skipped") AND NOT (ResponseQ1:0 AND ResponseQ2:0 AND ResponseQ3:"skipped") - Thanks, this seemed to work. I'm doing some additional verification now.

Comment: You don't need to specify `AND NOT` since `NOT` itself means what you intend to request. glad it helped :)